# Multicolumn/multirow inside align

Tags: align, arrays, multirow

Is there a way to use `\multicolumn` or `\multirow` inside an `array` environment which is inside `align` environment?
For instance, the following piece of code gives me an error. What is the way around this? I want $4$ to span the first two columns.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 3 & \cdots & \multicolumn{2}{*}{4}\\
1 & 1 & 3 & \cdots &\\
1 & 1 & 3 & \cdots &\\
1 & 1 & 3 & \cdots &\\
1 & 1 & 3 & \cdots &\\
\end{array}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used the argument syntax of `\multirow` but wrote `\multicolumn` (and didn't include the `multirow` package):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 3 & \cdots & \multirow{2}{*}{4}\\
1 & 1 & 3 & \cdots &\\
1 & 1 & 3 & \cdots &\\
1 & 1 & 3 & \cdots &\\
1 & 1 & 3 & \cdots &\\
\end{array}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Does the same work for multicolumn as well, if we want an element to occupy two columns?

Comment: @user17762 yes neither multicolumn nor multirow is at all affected by an outer align.

Comment: I found that the entry inside the multirow is not in math mode, i.e., `\multirow{2}{*}{U_1}` doesn't work, I need to have `\multirow{2}{*}{$U_1$}`, even though the entire thing is inside the align environment.

Comment: @user17762 multirow's `*` form is affectively a `p` column and p columns in array are not in math mode (the outer align will not affect this)

Answer (score 21):

To get "`multicolumn`" in `align` (as asked in the title), I've [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4249199) that using `\omit\rlap{}` gives the desired result.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\omit\rlap{Formula} && \text{Description} \\
y &= x + 14 & \text{A linear formula} \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It took me a minute to catch this, so I'll point it out for everyone: the argument to \omit\rlap{} is parsed in text mode, not math mode. Use \omit\rlap{$contents$} if your "contents" is an equation

Comment: The $contents$ inside `\rlap` will be rendered differently. If the equation has a fraction then it will appear smaller inside `\rlap{$\frac{a}{b}$}`. Use `\rlap{$\displaystyle \frac{a}{b}$}`

Comment: @TimKuipers @user1476176 Or simply use `\mathrlap{\frac{a}{b}}` instead of `\rlap{$\displaystyle \frac{a}{b}$}`. Requires `\usepackage{mathtools}`.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using `\rlap`, you can use 
`\multispan2{$\displaystyle contents$\hfil}`

`\omit` and `\multispan` are the plain Tex equivalents of `\multicolumn`. `\omit` just removes all of the formatting that `{align}` puts in and lets you format the table cell as you wish. `Multispan` gives you a true two-column cell (so if your two-column cell is the widest thing in the table it will set the column width properly) but you have to tell TeX how to format the cell contents afterwards.

The `\hfil` moves the cell contents over to the left. The `$`s make it in math mode. The `\displaystyle` puts it in display math mode--if you have a `\sum` or `\int` in your contents, it will be in inline text style (too small) unless you remind TeX that you are in a displayed math environment.