# Merging inside align-environment

Tags: align

An `align`-environment allows for line-splitting and aligning as in table columns when writing math in latex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
      lefthandside1 &= righthandside1\\
      lefthandside2 &= righthandside2\\
      lefthandside3 &= righthandside3\\
      lefthandside4 &= righthandside4
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

All equal-signs `=` will be right under one another because of `&`.

I need to add a remark in-between two math-lines. Something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
      lefthandside1 &= righthandside1\\
      lefthandside2 &= righthandside2\\
      This is a remark before the third line.\\
      lefthandside3 &= righthandside3\\
      lefthandside4 &= righthandside4
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Essentially this extra line must merge the two "columns" that the `&` symbol has created on all other lines. It should act like a normal text-line and not be split or aligned. If I don't include a `&`, then the end of the remark is still aligned according to the other lines.

Is it possible to merge "columns" (or "ignore" the `&` splitting) on a specific line, without altering the others?

[ShareLatex example here](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/58e4e28a54b8ca05149425b0).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this remark line is not part of the math lines, then using `intertext{..}` is another way for doing this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
      lefthandside1 &= righthandside1\\
      lefthandside2 &= righthandside2
      \intertext{This is a remark before the third line.}
      lefthandside3 &= righthandside3\\
      lefthandside4 &= righthandside4
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Another method is to use `\noalign{..}`. This will be similar to the `\shortintertext`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
      lefthandside1 &= righthandside1\\
      lefthandside2 &= righthandside2\\
      \noalign{This is a remark before the third line.}
      lefthandside3 &= righthandside3\\
      lefthandside4 &= righthandside4
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

You could use TeX's multispan (inspiration [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368313/124577)).

[image: multispan]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
      lefthandside1 &= righthandside1\\
      lefthandside2 &= righthandside2\\
      \multispan2{Remark before the third line\hfil}\\
      lefthandside3 &= righthandside3\\
      lefthandside4 &= righthandside4
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `shortintertext` of the `mathtools`-package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
      lefthandside1 &= righthandside1\\
      lefthandside2 &= righthandside2\\
      \shortintertext{\hfil This is a remark before the third line.}
      lefthandside3 &= righthandside3\\
      lefthandside4 &= righthandside4
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you leave out the `\hfil` the remark is flushed left.

Comment: I don't see why the remark should not be flushleft?

Comment: I added a comment in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have already found your answer, intertext{..} is what you want. But the answer to your question is using \span instead of & in the related row.

```
\begin{align*}
  lefthandside1 &= righthandside1\\
  lefthandside2 &= righthandside2\\
  This is a remark before the third line. \span\\
  lefthandside3 &= righthandside3\\
  lefthandside4 &= righthandside4
\end{align*}
```