# Properly using multispan in align

Tags: tables, align, multicolumn

Alas, if one searches for `multispan` and/or `omit` one nearly exclusively finds questions for table-errors. Inspired from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368313/27717) I try to use `multispan` to achieve multi-column entries in an `alignat`-environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat*}{3}
        A &= abc &&= abc &&= abc\\
        &\omit\multispan3{%
            ${}=abcabcabcabc\hfil$
        }%
        &&= abc
    \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

The output looks as desired, but LaTeX nevertheless complains `Misplaced \omit. \end{alignat*}`. What would be the correct usage of `\multispan`?

Comment: Just remove `\omit`.  The `\multispan` already contains `\omit`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better don't use `\multispan` at all in this case.  It contains `\omit` which will remove the formatting from the cell which will throw you out of math mode (as you noticed).  Just put the appropriate number of primitive `\span` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat*}{3}
        A &= abc &&= abc &&= abc\\
        &=abcabcabcabc \span\span &&= abc \\
        &= abc &&= abcabcabcabcabcabc &&= abc\\
    \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not give correct alignment of the spanned cell is not dominating the width of the columns involved. Also, putting in `\hfill`'s does not help.

Comment: @Bubaya Do you want it like the updated answer?  The placement of `\span` matters.