# How to exit alignment in align?

Tags: align, gather

How can I get equations of "gathered type" inside an align environment?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    V1:
    \begin{align}
        a &= b + b + b\\
        \begin{gathered}
            \pi \approx 3.1415926535
        \end{gathered} \\
        &= c \\
        &= d
    \end{align}
    V2:
    \begin{gather}
        a = b + b + b \\
        \pi \approx 3.1415926535 \\
        \hphantom{a} = c + c \hphantom{, + b }\\
        \hphantom{a} = d \hphantom{, + b + b }
    \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

V2 is what I want it to look like, but I obviously don't want to manually align the equations.
[image: rendered MWE]

Comment: The non-MWE would be an Integral where I'd want to insert a substitution to polar-coordinates, but i want to align the integral before and after.

Comment: Your requirement is not very clear. Could you post an example of the real situation (as code, not an image!)

Comment: They cannot be mixed this that (and probably should not). If the gather stuff comes first or last you can place an align inside a gather

Comment: This answer should give you a line on a solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113291/multicolumn-multirow-inside-align

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simple `align` with one alignment point, you can use a variant of the `\Cen` macro I proposed in other answers.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Cen}[1]{%
  \ifmeasuring@
  \else
    \dimen0=\ifcase1\maxcolumn@widths\fi
    \dimen2=\ifcase2\maxcolumn@widths\fi
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[\dimexpr(\width+\dimen0-\dimen2)/2][l]{$\displaystyle#1$}}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a &= b + b + b\\
\Cen{\pi \approx 3.1415926535} \\
  &= c \\
  &= d
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

On the first pass, the material inside `\Cen` is ignored. On the second pass we know the widths of the columns and we can do a bit of algebra; the material is in a zero width box (otherwise the computations of the widths would be affected, inside which there is a box as wide as “width of the material plus width of the first column minus width of the second column, all divided by two”, with the excess material sticking out to the right.

[image]

You can also use

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\Cen}[1]{%
  \multispan{2}\hfill\makebox[0pt]{$\displaystyle#1$}\hfill\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a &= b + b + b\\
\Cen{\pi \approx 3.1415926535} \\
  &= c \\
  &= d
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: neat! I don't understand it. What's the difference in the two versions?
I think I'm gonna get on reading the TexBook this semester break, any other recommendations?

Comment: @josh The difference is that in the former version we do the computations; in the latter they're done by TeX.