# Improve spaces in equations

Tags: math-mode, spacing

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,amsthm,mathtools,systeme}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
\newcommand{\isEquivTo}[1]{\underset{#1}{\sim}}
\begin{document}
\noindent On considère les fonctions suivantes :
\[
\begin{array}{ll}
{\rm (1)}\ f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x^2-3x+2 & \text{si } x\leq 1\\
-\sqrt{x-1} & \text{si } x>1
\end{array}\right.  \quad\quad\quad&
{\rm (2)}\ g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{x}{1+e^{\frac{1}{x}}} & \text{si } x\neq0\\
0 & \text{si } x=0
\end{array}\right.
\\
{\rm (3)}\ h(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x^2-3x+2 & \text{si } x\leq 1\\
-\sqrt{x-1} & \text{si } x>1
\end{array}\right.  \quad\quad\quad&
{\rm (4)}\ k(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{x}{1+e^{\frac{1}{x}}} & \text{si } x\neq0\\
0 & \text{si } x=0
\end{array}\right.
\end{array}
\]
\begin{itemize}
  \item [(1)] Les fonctions $f, g, h$ et $k$ sont-elles continues en $0$? justifier votre réponse.
  \item [(2)] Les fonctions $f, g, h$ et $k$ sont-elles dérivables en $0$? justifier votre réponse.
  \item [(3)] Les fonctions $f, g, h$ et $k$ sont-elles de classe $C^1$ en $0$? justifier votre réponse.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

> I want to minimize some spaces (-) and to increase other spaces (+)

[image]

Comment: `\rm` hasn't been defined by by default in latex since 1993  `\mathrm{(4)}` would be the normal form although simply `(4)` produces the same output as parenthesis and digits come from the roman font by default

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd like to suggest that you encase the four short equations in an `alignat*` environment. In addition, I'd like to suggest that you employ `dcases*` environments (provided by the `mathtools` package) instead of `\begin{array}{ll} ... \end{array}\right.`.

If you wish to reduce the amounts of vertical whitespace that get inserted before and after displayed equations globally, you could execute something like

```
\addtolength\abovedisplayskip{-4pt} % default: 12pt plus 3pt minus 7pt
\addtolength\belowdisplayskip{-4pt} % ditto
```

in the preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % "latin1" -- really??
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}  % <-- new
\usepackage{%amsfonts, % is loaded automatically by amssymb
            %amsmath,  % is loaded automatically by mathtools
            amssymb,
            mathtools,
            amsthm,
            graphicx,
            systeme,
            pifont,    % bouni
            enumitem } % <-- new 
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
\newcommand{\isEquivTo}[1]{\underset{#1}{\sim}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % localize scope of the next two instructions
\addtolength\abovedisplayskip{-4pt} 
\addtolength\belowdisplayskip{-4pt} 

\noindent 
On considère les fonctions suivantes:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
(1)\ f(x) &=
     \begin{dcases*}
         x^2-3x+2    & si $x\leq 1$\\
         -\sqrt{x-1} & si $x>1$
     \end{dcases*}  
     &\qquad % insert horizontal spacing
(2)\ g(x) &=
     \begin{dcases*}
         \tfrac{x}{1+e^{1/x}} & si $x\neq0$\\
         0                    & si $x=0$
     \end{dcases*}
\\[2\jot] % extra vertical separation
(3)\ h(x) &= 
     \begin{dcases*}
         x^2-3x+2    & si $x\leq 1$\\
         -\sqrt{x-1} & si $x>1$
     \end{dcases*}  
     & %\qquad
(4)\ k(x) &=
     \begin{dcases*}
         \tfrac{x}{1+e^{1/x}} & si $x\neq0$\\
          0                   & si $x=0$
     \end{dcases*}
\end{alignat*}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*),left=0pt]
\item Les fonctions $f, g, h$ et $k$ sont-elles continues en $0$? 
justifier votre réponse.
\item Les fonctions $f, g, h$ et $k$ sont-elles dérivables en $0$? 
justifier votre réponse.
\item Les fonctions $f, g, h$ et $k$ sont-elles de classe $C^1$ en $0$? 
justifier votre réponse.
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment: Indeed replacing `\frac` with `\frac` in questions 2 and 4 would cause a typographic disaster, especially if `e^{1/x}` with `e^{\frac{1}{x}}`. I see no harm in employing inline-fraction notation, though, i.e., in replacing `\tfrac{x}{1+e^{1/x}}` with `x/(1+e^{1/x})`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Yes, I wish to reduce the amounts of vertical whitespace that get inserted before and after displayed equations globally. What can I do? thanks

Comment: @Student - I've added the instructions `\addtolength\abovedisplayskip{-4pt}` and
`\addtolength\belowdisplayskip{-4pt}` to the code and posted an updated screenshot. To make the scope of these instructions global, place them in the preamble.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I think you have used ``\begingroup`` in order to incorporate the changes for all the text. I think I can delete it if I wish only to reduce spaces in some places. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Student - I used `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` to limit the scope of the `\addtolength` directives to a part of the document. To make the scope global, get rid of `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` and place the `\addtolength` directives in the preamble.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I find a problem in your answer. When I use \frac it looks so huge. With \tfrac it is not so clear. Is there a solution? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Student - The code shown above deliberately uses `\tfrac`, *not* `\frac`. Please explain what do you mean with "it is not so clear". Too small, maybe? Have you considered replacing the `\tfrac` notation with inline-fraction notation, e.g., `x/(1+e^{1/x})` instead of `\tfrac{x}{1+e^{1/x}}`?

Comment: For example if I write ``\frac{x}{1+e^{\frac1x}}`` instead of ``\tfrac{x}{1+e^{1/x}}`` it looks huge and not so nice. I don't prefer to use ``1/x``. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Student - Not sure why you dislike inline-fraction notation, à la `1/x`. It's been around for more than  200 years and has proven its usefulness. Donald Knuth did *not* invent inline-fraction notation; he just made it easy for TeX users to employ. I definitely agree with you that `\frac{x}{1+e^{\frac1x}}` doesn't look good at all. But if you persist in using `\frac{x}{1+e^{\frac1x}}` anyway, you have only yourself to blame for producing a typographically unappealing and inferior outcome.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using the tabularray package (\begin{tblr} instead of \begin{array}). It will increase the space within the arrays, but not around your \[ ... \].

For the spaces between your equations, you could search in the direction of amsmath. See for instance [Multicolumn/multirow inside align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113291/multicolumn-multirow-inside-align)